# How can I change the font in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: fonts, sublime-text-2

How would I go about changing the font in Sublime 2?

This is what my settings look like:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/User/Monokai Soda.tmTheme",
    "font_size": 12,

    "theme": "Soda Dark.sublime-theme"
}
```

Answer (score 11):

From my Preferences | Settings-User:

```
{
  "font_face": "Consolas",
  "font_size": 11,
  "word_wrap": false
}
```

See documentation: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/font.html

Comment: To disable anti-aliasing add: `"font_options": ["no_antialias"],`